# Convert -WebKit-Filter hue into RGB

Tags: css, webkit, imagefilter

The `-webkit-filter` in CSS3 allows you to apply a hue filter by passing a degree value between 0-360

example:

```
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(80deg);
```

How would you convert the degree value into an RGB value?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS filter hue-rotate is not a true hue-rotation, it's an approximation in RGB space, and is not very accurate for saturated colors. If you want to duplicate what it's doing you need to use the same algorithm - which is not the standard HSL/RGB conversion. Its underlying algorithm is in the [SVG 1.1 filter spec for feColorMatrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement)

For type="hueRotate", ‘values’ is a single one real number value (degrees). A hueRotate operation is equivalent to the following matrix operation:

```
| R' |     | a00  a01  a02  0  0 |   | R |
| G' |     | a10  a11  a12  0  0 |   | G |
| B' |  =  | a20  a21  a22  0  0 | * | B |   
| A' |     | 0    0    0    1  0 |   | A |
| 1  |     | 0    0    0    0  1 |   | 1 |

where the terms a00, a01, etc. are calculated as follows:

| a00 a01 a02 |    [+0.213 +0.715 +0.072]
| a10 a11 a12 | =  [+0.213 +0.715 +0.072] + 
| a20 a21 a22 |    [+0.213 +0.715 +0.072]

                        [+0.787 -0.715 -0.072]
cos(hueRotate value) *  [-0.213 +0.285 -0.072] +
                        [-0.213 -0.715 +0.928]

                        [-0.213 -0.715+0.928]
sin(hueRotate value) *  [+0.143 +0.140-0.283]
                        [-0.787 +0.715+0.072]
```